# Get-SmbShareAccess changed in Windows Server 2012 R2 Powershell v4?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I have been using Get-SmbShare and Get-SmbShareAccess to get to my share permissions on a WSS 2012 FailoverCluster from Windows Server 2012 with Powershell v3 using the pipeline like this:

```
Get-SmbShare -Scopename XXX -CimSession XXX  | Get-SmbShareAccess
```

Now that I got a Windows Server 2012 R2 with Powershell v4 I'm out of luck, using the same pipeline to query the WSS 2012 Cluster I'm getting:

> Exception calling "EndProcessing" with "0" argument(s): "Exception getting "SmbInstance": "Cannot convert null to type
>   "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.SmbShare.SmbInstance" due to enumeration values that are not valid.
>   Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Default, CSV".""
>   At line:603 char:17
>   +                 $__cmdletization_objectModelWrapper.EndProcessing()
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetValueInvocationException

When I issue the command for the shares local to the 2012 R2 server, everything is fine. Also when I query non-clustered shares on a remote 2012 R2 server.

As soon as I try to query shares on a 2012 (without R2) server, I get the stated error.

Any ideas or comments?

Comment: A Windows 2012 with Powershell v4 also works fine. It really seems to be related to 2012 vs 2012 R2.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See the answer posted to the same question posted on the [Microsoft Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b5d0a818-f777-4115-8ce2-9a2804d6271d/using-getsmbshareaccess-in-the-pipeline-on-windows-server-2012-r2?forum=winserverpowershell) for a workaround.